# Setup item permissions using sharepoint workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, permissions

I have a SharePoint 2013 workflow that was created for us by a third party.

There is one copy of the workflow deployed on a test install of sharepoint and one in production. It is applied to a Document library in each.

The one in test has one action that reads:

```
Setup permission for Variable:Leader on [%CurrentItem:Encoded Absolute URL%] with Current Item:ID
```

See screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of production workflow]

On the production workflow it reads:

```
Setup permission for Variable:Leader on [%CurrentItem:Encoded Absolute URL%] with Current Item:
```

See screenshot: 
[image: Screenshot of test server workflow]

Notice on the production one the "ID" is missing (along with other columns - such as Modified By, Approval Status etc.). When I select the text "Current Item:" the ID option is not in the drop down, yet it is there for the one on my test site.

I believe this workflow may have been originally created in Visual Studio.

I've tried re-adding this action using SharePoint Designer, but the CurrentItem: ID is still not available.

Any ideas on how I can get this to match my test site?

Comment: Are you able to see the ID column in the production library itself?

Comment: No. However I never see the ID column in the Library Settings page. In this case I don't see it in my test site or my production site. However I know the ID is working because I can browse to various documents in my Library using the ID in the url  - such like... http://intranet/Policies/workspace/Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=99

Comment: Right..but you should be able to add it to the view and see it. What are you trying to modify the workflow with, SPD?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SPD to modify the workflow. I don't believe this has anything to do with a list "view". I am not able to add an ID column under Library settings.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the list wasn't corrupted or something. If you're able to add and see ID in a view, it's there. Just have to figure out why it's not showing in SPD. You won't see ID in the library settings. It's an internal field.

Comment: Please post screenshots of both workflows where you are trying to make the update.

Comment: Ok, I've added screenshots to the question above. I also checked my View options and the ID column is available and works if I turn check to show it in the View.

Comment: Notice ID is not the only missing column...

Comment: Very odd. Is this happening with other list? What happens if you try to create a new workflow?

Comment: No. If I create a new workflow on the same list it's fine. Makes me think it's a problem with the workflow's association to the list, or to the content type but everything looks ok. I would like to avoid recreating the entire workflow since it's long and complicated.

Comment: it sounds like the workflow is corrupted.